# Vim resize horizantal splits

Tags: linux, vim, terminal

I want to resize horizontal splits in vim. I have a vim script solution for vertical splits. I have checked online but no one talks about how to resize horizontal splits. I have a couple of failed attempts. both the vimscript solution for vertical splits and my failed attempts are below.

script to resize vertical splits

```
" resize splits
noremap <silent> <C-S-Right> :vertical resize -1<CR>
noremap <silent> <C-S-Left> :vertical resize +1<CR>
```

failed attempt to resize horizontally splits

```
noremap <silent> <C-S-Up> :split resize +1<CR>
noremap <silent> <C-S-Down> :split resize -1<CR>
```

Comment: Those are basic mappings, not what is commonly referred to as "vimscript". What do you want those mappings to do? Did you read `:help :resize`? Does it mention `:help :split`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also reuse the built-in mappings:

```
noremap <silent> <c-s-right> <c-w><
noremap <silent> <c-s-left> <c-w>>
noremap <silent> <c-s-up> <c-w>+
noremap <silent> <c-s-down> <c-w>-
```

Beware that the left/right commands move the right border of the current window, while the up/down commands move the bottom border. Your bindings have inverted these directions, which makes me think you have a different expectation.

Answer (score 2):

```
noremap <silent> <C-S-Up> :resize +1<CR>
noremap <silent> <C-S-Down> :resize -1<CR>
```